# Shell executes command from different path to the one shown by which in RedHat6

Tags: python, bash, unix, redhat

I've just noticed that when calling python from the command line, it just calls python from /usr/bin/python on account that it started v2.6:

```
$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jun 11 2019, 11:01:44)
```

However, when running "which python", it correctly points to a newer version installed in a conda environment, calling it directly I see it starts the expected newer version.

```
$ which python
~/miniconda3/bin/python
$ ~/miniconda3/bin/python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 07:30:14)
```

Python hasn't been aliased:

```
$ alias | grep python
$
```

and the conda environment path comes before the standard "/usr/bin" in my $PATH, so I don't understand why it executes python from "/usr/bin".

Any idea what could be going on?

Comment: `type python` , `hash python` `hash -r`

Comment: `which` is a nonstandard command which may or may not display bogus information. Use your shell's built-in commands  `type` and `command` to query which commands, aliases, and functions are available.

Comment: Thanks, afterr rrunning hash the shell now executes the right version of python.